# Installing .net Application

Tags: c#

Is there anyway to to install .net Application **without** installing .net framework.

I use .netFramework 2.0 .

And I do not want remotesoft .

Comment: Your application won't work if .NET framework is not installed

Comment: His application will work if .NET framework is not installed using Xenocode

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are/were at least two products which could convert a .NET application into a native application, which no longer requires the .NET framework to be installed:

- http://www.xenocode.com/
- http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/intro.html (which is what you don't want)

I have never used these tools, so I can't comment any further.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course there is, simply copy the files at the target folder but bare in mind that this application won't work if you don't install the framework.

Comment: I don't think he meant to just "install", but not run the application, but technically, yes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible. ıf you have install problems **clickonce** is very usefull. clickonce has automatic instals of dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, this scenario is not supported by anyone but people selling you products (such as Remotesoft Salamander).  Microsoft in particular does not support this.

There are ways to package the .NET framework with your installer so that you the user doesn't have to manually deploy the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do and which is supported by Microsoft would be:
Include the .net framework in the installer for your software. So your customer has to start only one setup, which will install the framework **and** your application.
You can do this with a Visual Studio setup project.

I don't know if that's what you want, though.
From the question it's not clear if you don't want a separate install for the framework (which you wouldn't have with a setup project) or if you don't want the framework on your machine at all (which is not possible in a way supported by MS, as indicated in the other answers).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, "No".
To run .NET Applications you need the .net framework.

There are tools that you can use to compile the IL into native code, but you will lose all the advantages of .NET framework, because that will not be a .NET application.